# How to run pre-requisite script into rest assured

Tags: testing, postman, rest-assured

How will run the pre-requisite script while doing the API automation.

I want to run pre-requisite script into rest assured

In postman we have tab to run pre-requisite script.. same how will run while automating API.
Please guide here

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a beforeAll method wherever you configure your Rest-assured framework or simply before your actual test class.

```
     @BeforeAll
     public static void beforeAll() {
        // your code here
     }
```